# How to mass rename files with multiple dots in Batch file?

Tags: batch-file, rename, dos

I have the following folders structure:

```
C:\Database
C:\Database\Tables
C:\Database\Stored Procedures
C:\Database\Views
C:\Database\Functions
```

There will lots of files in each of the **Tables**, **Stored Procedures**, **Views** and **Functions** folders of the following format:

Under the **Tables** folder:

```
dbo.Table1Name.Table.sql
dbo.Table2Name.Table.sql
mon.Table3Name.Table.sql
test.Table4Name.Table.sql
```

Under the **Stored Procedures** folder:

```
dbo.usp_StoredProcedure1Name.StoredProcedure.sql
dbo.usp_StoredProcedure2Name.StoredProcedure.sql
dbo.usp_StoredProcedure3Name.StoredProcedure.sql
mon.usp_StoredProcedure4Name.StoredProcedure.sql
mon.usp_StoredProcedure5Name.StoredProcedure.sql
```

and likewise for **Views** and **Functions**.

The files under the **Tables** folder would then be renamed to:

```
dbo.Table1Name.sql
dbo.Table2Name.sql
mon.Table3Name.sql
test.Table4Name.sql
```

And the name of files under the **Stored Procedures** folder would then be:

```
dbo.usp_StoredProcedure1Name.sql
dbo.usp_StoredProcedure2Name.sql
dbo.usp_StoredProcedure3Name.sql
mon.usp_StoredProcedure4Name.sql
mon.usp_StoredProcedure5Name.sql
```

Ideally, I'd have a batch file in the Database folder that renames the files that remove ***Table***, ***StoredProcedure***, ***View*** and ***Function*** from the name of the files in their respective folders.

If it can't be easily done in Batch file, I'd try to find something in PowerShell.

Thanks Alex K for editing my original post (my first post) and thanks foxidrive for your recomendation and KnightWhoSayNi sharing your way.

Comment: Some examples of your actual files will help to you give exact code, as the code will often change depending on the makeup of the names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch this and it will `display the ren commands` on the screen.
If it is right then remove the `echo` and run it again to perform the renames.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "C:\Database\*.sql" /b /s /a-d ') do (
   for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%b in ("%%~nxa") do echo ren "%%a" "%%b.%%c%%~xa"
)
pause
```

Comment: I think this is close but not quite there yet. I'm getting these when I test it: ren "C:\Database\Tables\a.b1.Table.sql" "C:\Database\Tables\a.b1.sql" which has syntax error. The second parameter to the ren command needs to be just the file name (without the path). Thanks

Comment: Ok I have managed to make a bit of changes to get it working. Thanks for you help. I added cd C:\Database\Tables after echo off and removed /s /a-d. Also 'dir...' was changed to just 'dir *.sql /b'

Comment: I edited the code in one term, which should fix the problem that you saw.

Answer (score 0):

**BEFORE YOUR UPDATE**

I wrote small batch script.

ex.

```
asd.first.second.txt -> asd.first.txt
aaa.first.second.txt -> aaa.first.txt
bbb.first.second.txt -> bbb.first.txt
ccc.first.second.txt -> ccc.first.txt
ddd.first.second.txt -> ddd.first.txt
```

**Important:** create batch script in the folder with your files

```
ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
CLS

SET temp_file=C:\temp\temp_string.txt
FOR /f "delims=" %%A IN ('DIR /B "%~dp0"') DO (
    ECHO %%A
    ECHO %%A > %temp_file%
    FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=." %%I IN (%temp_file%) DO (
        ECHO %%I %%J %%K
        rename %%I.%%J.%%K.txt %%I.%%J.txt
    )

)
DEL %temp_file%
```

Answer (score 0):

No batch script is needed. It can be done with a simple REN command on the command line! :-)

```
for %F in (Tables "Stored Procedures" Views Functions) do @ren "C:\Database\%~F\*.*.*.sql" "????????????.??????????????????????????????.sql"
```

Just make sure you have at least as many `?` as there are characters in the longest source file name.

Double the percents if you use the command in a batch script.

Here is another simple solution (batch script) using two REN commands:

```
@echo off
for %%F in (
  Tables:Table
  "Stored Procedures:StoredProcedure"
  Views:View
  Functions:Function
) do for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%A in ("%%~F") do (
  ren "C:\Database\%A\*.*.*.sql" *.
  ren "C:\Database\%A\*.*.%%B" *.sql
)
```

See [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090) for help in understanding why the above solutions work.

Comment: @user1533274 - Well... it isn't until I fix the code! I forgot the "tokens=1,2" option. All fixed now.